# Cartesian product from two Series, different lengths and indexes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given two series:

```py
import pandas as pd
ser1 = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3], index=[1,2,3])
ser2 = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3,4,5], index = ['a','b','c','d','e'])
```

How can I cross-multiply the two to get this desired output?

```py
pd.DataFrame(
data = [[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[3,6,9],[4,8,12],[5,10,15]],
index = ser2.index,
columns = ser1.index,)
```

My approach so far has been to build a temporary dataframe with index and cols matching the two series, and then iterate over one of the two series using iteritems(). I feel like there should be a cleaner way to achieve this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) for outer product of two `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(ser2, ser1), index = ser2.index, columns = ser1.index)

print (df)
   1   2   3
a  1   2   3
b  2   4   6
c  3   6   9
d  4   8  12
e  5  10  15
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use NumPy broadcasting to multiply the values of one series by the transposed values of the other.

```
res = pd.DataFrame(ser1.values * ser2.values[:, None],
                   index=ser2.index, columns=ser1.index)

print(res)

   1   2   3
a  1   2   3
b  2   4   6
c  3   6   9
d  4   8  12
e  5  10  15
```