# how to make pandas code faster or using dask dataframe or how to use vectorization for this type of problem?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization, dask

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# list of name, degree, score
label1 = ["a1", "a1", "a1","a1", "a2","a2","a2","a2", "b1","b1","b1","b1", "b2","b2","b2","b2"]
label2 = ["a1", "a2", "b1","b2", "a1","a2","b1","b2", "a1","a2","b1","b2", "a1","a2","b1","b2"]
m1 =     [ 0,     3,    2,  7,    3,   0,   5,    8,    2,   5,   0,   9,    7,  8,    9,   0]
  
# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'label1': label1, 'label2': label2,'m1':m1}     
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    
df
```

output of this dataframe:

```
 label1 label2 m1
0   a1  a1  0
1   a1  a2  3
2   a1  b1  2
3   a1  b2  7
4   a2  a1  3
5   a2  a2  0
6   a2  b1  5
7   a2  b2  8
8   b1  a1  2
9   b1  a2  5
10  b1  b1  0
11  b1  b2  9
12  b2  a1  7
13  b2  a2  8
14  b2  b1  9
15  b2  b2  0
```

I want to write a function that will take strings (samp1)a, (samp2)b, and a (df) data frame as input. We have to preprocess those two input strings so that we can get desired strings in our data frame. Then we need to access some particular rows' (like (a1,b1)  or (a2,b2)) indices of the data frame to get their corresponding 'm1' value. Next, we will make some (addition) operations for those m1 values and store them in two variables and after that, it will return the minimum of two variables. [looking at coding snippet may be easier to understand]
The following is the code for this function:

```
def min_4line(samp1,samp2,df):
  k=['1','2']
  #k and samp are helping to generate variable along with number
  #for example it will take a,b and can create a1,a2,b1,b2.....
  samp1_1=samp1+k[0]
  samp1_2=samp1+k[1]
  
  samp2_1=samp2+k[0]
  samp2_2=samp2+k[1]
  
  #print(samp1_1)#a1
  #print(samp1_2)#a2
  #print(samp2_1)#b1
  #print(samp2_2)#b2
  """
  #As we are interested about particular rows to get comb1 variable, we need those row's 
  #indexes
  #for comb1 we want to sum (a1,b1)[which located at ind1] and (a2,b2)[which located at ind2]
  #same types of thing for comb2
  """
  ind1=df.index[(df['label1']==samp1_1) & (df['label2']==samp2_1)].tolist()
  ind2=df.index[(df['label1']==samp1_2) & (df['label2']==samp2_2)].tolist()
  #print(ind1)#[2]
  #print(ind2)#[7]
  
  comb1=int(df.loc[ind1,'m1'])+int(df.loc[ind2,'m1'])
  #print('comb1: ',comb1)#comb1:  10
    
  ind3=df.index[(df['label1']==samp1_2) & (df['label2']==samp2_1)].tolist()
  ind4=df.index[(df['label1']==samp1_1) & (df['label2']==samp2_2)].tolist()
  #print(ind3)#[6]
  #print(ind4) #[3]   
  comb2=int(df.loc[ind3,'m1'])+int(df.loc[ind4,'m1'])
  #print('comb2: ',comb2)#comb2:  12
  return min(comb1,comb2)#10
```

To append unique char like a,b from the dataframe we need to do a list operation:

```
#this list is needed so that I can compare how many unique values are there... 
#it could get a,b,c,d.... and make comparison 
#like (a,b), (a,c),(a,d), (b,c),(b,d),(c,d) for the function
list_line=list(df['label1'].unique())

string_test=[a[:-1] for a in list_line]
#string_test will exclude number portion of character
list_img=sorted(list(set(string_test)))

#print(list_img)#['a', 'b']
#print(len(list_img))#2
```

Now we need to create a data frame that will go over the 'list_img' and call the min4line function to get value like (a,b), (a,c) and corresponding output of the function. Here a nested loop is necessary as suppose list consist [a,b,c,d]. it will go like(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d),(c,d). So that we can have unique pair. The code for this is:

```
%%time
d=[]
for i in range(len(list_img)):  
  for j in range(i+1,len(list_img)):
    a=min_4line(list_img[i],list_img[j],df)
    print(a)
    d.append({'label1':str(list_img[i]),'label2':str(list_img[j]), 'metric': str(a)})
dataf=pd.DataFrame(d)
dataf.head(5)
```

output is:

```
  label1label2metric
0   a   b   10
```

Is there any way to make the code faster? I broke down the problem into small parts. this operation is needed for 16 million rows. I am interested in using dask for this. But when I have asked this type of question previously, many people failed to understand as I was not able to state the problem clearly. Hope this time I broke it down in easier format. You can copy those code cell and run in jupyter notebook to check the output and suggest me any good way to make the program faster.
[updated]
Can anyone suggest, how can I get those particular indices of those rows using numpy or any kind of vectorized operation?

Comment: yes 16 million.

Comment: take a look at [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). don't use for loops. I really recommend that you read a few guides on pandas vectorization.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, thanks for ur comment, can u  please elaborate at how can I use pd.merge?I mean the function accessing the data frame is doing some comparison, not merging

Comment: you're essentially trying to do super simple math and comparisons with the outer product of a bunch of combinations of your original series indices. I think you should do this all at once, e.g. using the techniques in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51401878/3888719. Looping over all all combinations and indexing into the dataframe each time will always be super slow.